# postgreSQL archive process failed on

Tags: postgresql

I upgraded a cluster from 8.3 to 8.4.  Things seemed to be fine so I dropped the 8.3 cluster.  Then noticed an error and found that the archive_command was still pointing to the 8.3 data directory

```
archive_command = 'cp "%p" /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/wal_archives/"%f"'
```

I changed this to 8.4 but now continually get the following errors in the log file and process list for one specific file

```
2014-10-09 17:02:12 CDT DETAIL:  The failed archive command was: cp "pg_xlog/000000010000000000000012" /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/wal_archives/"000000010000000000000012"
cp: cannot create regular file `/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/wal_archives/000000010000000000000012': No such file or directory
 4122 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ postgres: archiver process   failed on 000000010000000000000012
```

I'm not sure the best way to recover from this.  As far as I can tell the database is fully functional

Comment: Well, does `/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/wal_archives/` exist?

Comment: It does now.  Seems so obvious now that you said it.  I think your answer. "Make sure the wal_archive directory exits" is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to ensure that `/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/wal_archives` exists.

You will also want to ensure it's writeable by the `postgres` user, though if this was a permissions problem the error would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the user postgres is owner of this dir (/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/wal_archives) or he can write to this! (chwon/chmod)
Also it is better that you don't you this path /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main/ better you use an other device or storage.